# Sou obrigado a utilizar um laço de repetição se minha consulta LINQ retornar apenas um objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Minha classe:

```
public class Carros {
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Atributo2 { get; private set; }
    public int Atributo3 { get; private set; }}}
```

Supondo que o atributo ID não pudesse se repetir e que eu crie uma collection do tipo dessa classe e quisesse retornar dessa collection apenas o carro que tivesse ID == 2

Então eu faria:

```
var carroId2 = from carro in collectionCarros
                       where carro.ID == 2
                       select new {
                           Id = carro.ID
                       };
```

E queria poder fazer algo como `carroId2.ID` para retorna o valor do atributo, mas eu só posso fazer isso dentro de um laço ? Ou existe outra forma de poder fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. Se quiser continuar fazendo assim e portanto ainda recebeu um `IEnumerable`, tem que acessar um elemento, não pode acessar o objeto direto porque ele é um objeto coleção de dados e quer o objeto individual.:

```
carroId2[0].ID
```

Então o nome da variável nem poderia ser essa (a variável `carro` também está errada, o nome da classe também está porque ali tem um só carro e não faz sentido estar no plural), você tem **carros** ali, que por acaso você sabe que só tem um, mas é uma coleção de carros muito pequena. Se quer pegar o objeto individual (usei a sua variável ainda que o nome esteja conceitualmente errado)

Mas você pode pegar só objeto:

```
carroId2.FirstOrDefault().ID
```

O ideal é verificar se o objeto está nulo porque pode achar nenhum elemento, quase o mesmo teria que ser feito pela coleção de dados (só que bastaria ver se a coleção está vazia). Se tiver certeza absoluta que não pode vir zero objetos (eu não teria tanta assim) pode usar o `First()`, se achar nada terá uma exceção, porque seria um erro inesperado.

Se quiser pegar todo o objeto pode fazer direto:

```
carro.FirstOrDefault(carro.ID == 2)
```

E dá pra pegar só o ID direto:

```
carro.FirstOrDefault(carro.ID == 2).ID
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Find.cs).